# Code not executing when condition is accomplished

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, positioning

I'm trying to organize some transforms in hierarchy by changing those transforms parents by code. I have this function:

```
private GameObject[,] SpawnCullingGroups(GameObject[,] cG)
     {
         for(int i = 0; i < cG.GetLength(0); i++)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < cG.GetLength(1); j++)
             {
                 GameObject c = Instantiate(Culler, new Vector3(i * 32f,0,j * 32f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                 c.name = "CoullingGroup";
                 cG[i,j] = c;
                 foreach (Transform child in GameObject.Find("MapContainer").transform)
                 {
                     if (child.position.x >= c.transform.position.x && child.position.x <= (c.transform.position.x + 32)
                         && child.position.z >= c.transform.position.z && child.position.z <= c.transform.position.z + 32) {
                         child.parent = cG [i, j].transform;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

         return cG;
     }
```

Sometimes the if conditions triggers and changes it parent, but with some transforms it wont work.
I end up with some strange pattern: [image]

All that sector (10 * 10) should be green (child of the CoullingGroup in that area).
Grids are perfect, meaning each block is 3.2 units length and 3.2 wide, and they are separated by 3.2 units in x and z axis.

Those who aren't child of the CullingGroup are in the range of condition.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you saying that the code inside `foreach (Transform child in GameObject.Find("MapContainer").transform)` is also being performed on Transforms that are not children of "MapContainer" game-object?

Comment: No, it's only performed on Transforms that are children of "MapContainer"

Comment: Your exact question is confusing. Where exactly in your code is it working not as intended?

Comment: All the children of "MapContainer" who are in range should change their parent to an CullingGroup and they don't.

Comment: I see. Well, I strongly suspect your error is in the line `if (child.position.x >= c.transform.position.x && child.position.x <= (c.transform.position.x + 32) && child.position.z >= c.transform.position.z && child.position.z <= c.transform.position.z + 32)` ... Do you know that the transform anchors by default are in the center of the object and not at its corner? Could that possibly be an issue here?

Comment: I know, it isn't, even if their anchor was in the corner, they would be inside the range, meaning: one child position is `(3.2f,0,3.2f)` and the CullingGroup position is `(0,0,0)` it is in range but it doesn't change it's parent.

Comment: That is informative. In the same if-condition line that I mentioned in my last comment, try using `32f` instead of `32`. Does that make a difference?

Comment: It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103330/discussion-between-andeart-and-patxiku).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @andeart we solved this by changing the loop into this:
foreach (Transform child in `GameObject.Find("MapContainer").GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())`

We also added another piece of code to avoid MapContainer be deleted.

```
if (child.name == "MapContainer") {
    continue;
}
```